# How do I explicitly use unchecked arithmetic operators in F#

Tags: f#

If I use the [--checked+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/compiler-options) option when compiling F# code, how do I use unchecked arithmetic for a specific operation.

Going the other way is easy, just use the [FSharp.Core.Operators.Checked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/operators.checked-module-%5Bfsharp%5D) module; but I can't find the appropriate module to get the Unchecked versions of the operators.

The [FSharp.Core.Operators.Unchecked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/operators.unchecked-module-%5bfsharp%5d) module exists, but does not contain any of the basic arithmetic operations such as `+`, `*`, etc.

For example:

```
let a = FSharp.Core.uint32.MaxValue
let b = a+1u //Alter this to get it to work?
//b should be 0,
//rather than OverflowException being thrown in the previous line
b
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default unchecked operators are defined in `Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators`. If you need this in just a few places, you can refer to the operator explicitly via the full module name:

```
let a = FSharp.Core.uint32.MaxValue
let b = Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators.(+) a 1u
```

Answer (score 3):

A more elaborate version of [Tomas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51673334/917053) where unchecked addition is redefined to continue using `infix` notation:

The following demo program

```
let (+!) x y = Operators.(+) x y

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
   try
       let _ = 1 + System.Int32.MaxValue
       printfn "Fine"
   with
       e -> printfn "Exception"

   try
       let _ = 1 +! System.Int32.MaxValue
       printfn "Fine"
   with
       e -> printfn "Exception"
   0
```

being compiled with `--checked+` flag and executed prints

```
Exception
Fine
```